# how can i transfer 5% of the contract balance?

Tags: solidity

If this was a calculation or something i'd do `myNumber * 5` and out of the contract (on client side) i'd do `myNumber / 100` but since solidity doesn't accept decimals i can't do this.

so my question is how can i transfer 5% of the contract balance?
thanks

Comment: `recipient.transfer(address(this).balance / 20)`

Comment: @goodvibration thanks, does this round the decimals?

Comment: It truncates (floors) the remainder of division by 20. This is typically negligible, because in the worst case, you'll "lose" 19 weis, which is 19 billionth of a billionth of ether.

Comment: For example, if the contract balance is 20.000000000000000019 ether, then you'll transfer 1 ether instead of 1.00000000000000000095 ether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `address recipient`, you can do:

```
recipient.transfer(address(this).balance / 20);
```

Note that although this truncates (floors) the remainder of division by 20, it is typically negligible because in the worst case you will "lose" 19 wei, where wei is a billionth of a billionth of ether.

For example, if the contract balance is 20.000000000000000019 ether, then you'll transfer 1 ether instead of 1.00000000000000000095 ether.